# my little asm program has a segment fault

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am a newbie to assembly language, and here is my little program.

```
section .data
section .text

global _start
_start:
    nop ; make gdb happy
    ; put your experiments here
    mov eax,4
    ; put your expeirments here
    nop ; make gdb happy

section .bss
```

This code is compiled with these commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs 001.asm -o 001.o
ld -o test 001.o
```

But when I run, it generates a core dump file with segment fault.
1.Why this little program has a segment fault? 
2.How to `gdb` this with core dump file?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFVDD.png)

Comment: For some very very short "quick start" (or more like idea, what to search for), check the very bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info (gdb, how to step over instructions).

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks. That help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program doesn't contain code that ends it. After executing the final `nop` in your code, the CPU continues to execute whatever the memory after that contains until it crashes. To fix this problem, tell the operating system to terminate your process. On amd64 Linux, you can use the following code:

```
mov eax,60  ; system call 60: exit
xor edi,edi ; set exit status to zero
syscall     ; call the operating system
```

Comment: I would say, since he is compiling with `-f elf64`it's likely that he wants a syscall not `int 80h`

Comment: @JeremyP Oh yes indeed, how could I miss this?